# Why does Array.prototype.reduce not have a thisObject parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Javascript Array methods such as `forEach` have a `thisArg` parameter, which is used as the context for invoking the callback:

```
array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

as do `every`, `some`, `filter` and `map`. However, `reduce` and `reduceRight` have no such parameter. Is there some particular reason for this, or some reason it is not necessary?

For instance, consider the following implementation of functional composition using `reduceRight`:

```
function compose () {
    var fns = [].slice.call(arguments,0);
    return function result() {
        return fns.reduceRight(
            function (prev,cur){
                return [cur.apply(this,prev)];
            },
            arguments
        )[0];
    };
}
```

I would like to make this "this-aware", so the functions being composed are called in the context in which the function returned by `compose` is invoked. Currently they appear to be invoked in the context of the global object. I could do the old `var self=this;` at the top of function `result`, and use that as the first argument to the `cur.apply` call, where I currently have `this`, but that would be unnecessary if `reduce` took a `thisArg` argument.

Am I missing something here, and is there something about `reduce` that makes this unnecessary or unuseful?

**UPDATE**

@kangax Yes, that occurred to me. Far be it from me to criticize the design of the API, but the signature for `reduce` seems a bit strange to me. The second optional argument functions differently than normal optional arguments, which typically just have a default value; instead its presence or absence changes the behavior, essentially overloading the function based on signature (argument count). When the second parameter is absent, the first element of the array becomes the starting value and the first call to the callback is against the second value. It seems to me that this behavior could be easily emulated by simply calling

```
array.slice(1).reduce(fn,array[0])
```

instead of building in special rules for the case where the second argument is omitted, which in turn, if your presumption is correct, also made it essentially impossible to figure out where to specify the `thisArg` argument. Then again, I am sure such issues were already debated while the spec was being hashed out, and there may be good reasons for such an approach.

Comment: Probably because 2nd argument in `reduce` is the initial value

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this with `reduceRight`? I think you can just as easily do this with `forEach` on a `reverse`d Array. Edit: I guess my point is that you're not looking to reduce the array of functions, but rather just run a set of input through the functions.

Comment: @tJener Of course you could do it with forEach (as underscore.js does), but I found a certain elegance in using reduce/Right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It becomes messy with two optional arguments, since `reduce`(`Right`) already covers two functionalities (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Special_folds_for_non-empty_lists)), which are distinguished in pure languages (e.g. named `foldl` and `foldl1` in Haskell). To cite [Brendan Eich](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.ecmascript4.general/4769/focus=4773):

> So this would mean reduce takes one callback argument and two optional arguments: thisObject and init. Which one should come first? The more common one is probably init, but then you separate the callback arg from the "thisObject" arg, which is maybe okay. Multiple optional arguments are kinda messy this way...
>
> Alternatively, we could just eliminate that extra "thisObject" argument, since people can always *[use binding]*.

I don't think it's a big issue, since these functional higher-order-functions are mostly used with <s>lamdba-</s>function-expressions anyway (like in your example). Of course there's a little inconsistency, but we can live with that. Image the alternative:

```
 array.reduce(callback[, initialValue[, thisArg]])
```

Can't be really used, we cannot really determine "[*if an initialValue was provided*](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.21)" since that means `arguments.length < 2` - we could pass `undefined` literally as well. So that means

```
 array.reduce(callback[, thisArg[, initialValue]])
```

which is ugly since we always needed to pass `null` or something to `thisArg` if we only wanted an initial value.

You noticed that already in your comment to Kangax ("*The second optional argument functions differently than normal optional arguments, […] its presence or absence changes the behavior*"), but I can't support your statement

> this behavior could be easily emulated by simply calling `array.slice(1).reduce(fn,array[0])`

as that would a) not work with a complex (chained) expression instead of the `array` variable and b) is cumbersome.

Answer (score 6):

You can always use this method :

```
array.reduce(callback.bind(context), initialValue);
```

... in order to attach a specific context to the callback function.

Answer (score 4):

On the Es-discuss mailing list you find in answer  http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.ecmascript4.general/4770

> The other methods with callbacks take a 'thisArg' not because it is
>   needed or even useful, but for compatibility, because they already do
>   in existing implementations that provide these functions.

Comment: Nice search result, however I find the other mails from the thread more relevant

Comment: By the time of the thread (March 2009), EcmaScript 5 was pretty much stable, undergoing only editorial changes. JavaScript as we know today was settled by end of 2008, along with any design rational. That's how I read the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a thisObject argument, bacause you can add a kind of thisObject in the accumulator and use the initial value to pass the thisObject.

Example:

```
thisObj = { some data }  // kind of this arg to be used in the reducer
const { view, used, totals } = sheetConfig.reduce(reducer, {
  view: [],    // initial  
  used: [],    // another initial
  totals: [],  // and one more initial
  thisObj      // and ...
});
```