# JS Array.prototype.filter on prototype method

Tags: javascript

Is there an easier way to call filter on a prototype method without an anonymous function?

I wonder if there is an equivalent to `myArray.filter(function(it){ it.method() })`.

This looks close to what might work (it doesn't):

```
function X() {}
X.prototype.method = function() { console.log(this); }

[new X(), new X()].filter(X.prototype.method.call);
```

Instead I get a TypeError in both latest Firefox and Chrome, it's because it doesn't quite do what I want:

```
x = function() { console.log(this) }
x.call(123) //logs 123
y = x.call //reports that y is of type function in console
y(123) //TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined
y.call(x, 123); //this is what you really need
```

I tried using bind, maybe I'm missing it, but if it's not a one-liner, it's not any better than the anonymous method form:

```
function X() {}
X.prototype.method = function() { console.log(this); }

y = X.prototype.method.call
y.bind(X.prototype.method)

[new X(), new X()].filter(y);
```

Comment: `.bind` returns a new function, it doesn't modify the function itself. So, `y = y.bind(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's set up some variables:

```
var method = X.prototype.method,
    array = [new X(), new X()];
```

Your attempt can now be written as:

```
array.filter(method.call);
```

The problem is that `call` is getting called but with no `this`. It needs a `this` of `method`. `method.call` is precisely the same as the raw `Function.prototype.call`, with no binding to any `this`. Merely saying `method.call` does not give you a version of `call` bound to `method`. To arrange for `call` to be bound to the right `this`, namely `method`, you need to, well, bind it:

```
array.filter(method.call.bind(method));
```

Walking through this:

1. `method.call.bind(method)` returns a new
   version of `Function#call` which is bound to `X#method`; think of it as
   `method.call(waiting)`, which is waiting to be called with a 
   value which will call `X#method` against a particular instance of X.
2. `Array#filter` passes each argument in the array to that bound version
   of `Function#call`, which results in `method.call(elt, remaining_args...)`,
   which is the equivalent of `elt.method(remaining_args...)`.

Output:

```
> array.filter(method.call.bind(method));
  X {method: function}
  X {method: function}
```

#### Some sugar

One could make this more semantic and readable with a little wrapper, which we will call `thisify`:

```
function thisify(fn) { return fn.call.bind(fn); }

array.filter(thisify(method));
```

#### Using the `context` parameter to `filter`

You could use the little-used `context` parameter of `filter` and its brethren (except [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867946/why-does-array-prototype-reduce-not-have-a-thisobject-parameter)), essentially, letting `filter` do the binding for you, if you choose to look at it that way, since

```
Array#filter(fn, context) === Array#filter(fn.bind(context))
```

So we can just write:

```
array.filter(method.call, method);
```

That actually looks cleaner to me. I doubt if it could get much simpler than that.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. The last way using the context parameter I like better than the bind. What I realize now though is that the advantage of the anonymous function is that you don't need to know if the method is on prototype or on each instance. But, I think in certain circumstances this could be a shorter way. I'm curious to try this out in JSPerf someday to see if there is a difference performance-wise.