# Array.map and lifted functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5

How come

```
var a = "foo /    bar/  baz  ".split('/');

a.map( function (e) { return String.prototype.trim.call(e) } )
```

works, while this doesn't...

```
a.map( String.prototype.trim );
```

Comment: may be this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186398/cant-use-string-prototype-trim-method-as-a-callback-for-array-map-filter

Comment: The answers are useful, but to keep yourself sane, you could also just do `a.map(function(e) { return e.trim(); })`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Array.prototype.filter on prototype method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214922/js-array-prototype-filter-on-prototype-method)

Comment: As pointed out in the question suggested as duplicate, one elegant solution is `a.map(Function.call, "".trim)`.

Comment: Or, you could simply do `split(/\s*\/\s*/)` and save yourself the mapping/trimming trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.map(Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.trim ))
```

The reason why this works and just mapping `String.prototype.trim` doesn't work is because, as others have pointed out, the `this` will be undefined when the function tries to trim the array element. What this solution does is, it creates a new function, which takes as it's `this` value as the function `String.prototype.trim`. Since the new function is a modified version of `Function.prototype.call`, as `map` calls this function passing it the array element, what essentially gets executed is: `Function.prototype.call.call(String.prototype.trim, element)`. This runs the function `String.prototype.trim` on the element passed in and you get the trimmed result.
This also would work:

```
 a.map(Function.call, "".trim)
```

by taking advantage of the fact that the second argument to `map` accepts the `thisArg`.
For a little bit of syntactic sugar, you can make a function that looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.mapUsingThis = function(fn) { return this.map(Function.call, fn); };
```

Then, you could just invoke

```
a.mapUsingThis("".trim)
```

like that.

Answer (score 0):

String.prototype.trim is a non params function, it will be called by string itself, but map function need a func arg accept a str as params

Comment: yeah but the param is still necessary because it is going to be used as `context`

Answer (score 0):

`'this'` refers to the string param in the first case whereas in the second case, 'this' becomes undefined as `String.prototype.trim` is not bound to any object.