# Native implementation of reduceRight in JavaScript is wrong

Tags: javascript, reduce, fold, associativity, commutativity

For an associative operation `f` over the elements of array `a`, the following relation should hold true: `a.reduce(f)` should be equivalent to `a.reduceRight(f)`.

Indeed, it does hold true for operations that are both associative and commutative. For
example:

```js
const a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

const add = (a, b) => a + b;

console.log(a.reduce(add));
console.log(a.reduceRight(add));
```

However it doesn't hold true for operations that are associative but not commutative. For example:

```js
const a = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]];

const concat = (a, b) => a.concat(b);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a.reduce(concat)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a.reduceRight(concat)));
```

We need to flip the arguments of `f` for `reduceRight` to make them equivalent:

```js
const a = [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9]];

const concat = (a, b) => a.concat(b);
const concatRight = (b, a) => a.concat(b);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a.reduce(concat)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(a.reduceRight(concatRight)));
```

This makes me believe that the native implementation of `reduceRight` is wrong.

I believe that the `reduceRight` function should be implemented as follows:

```js
var REDUCE_ERROR = "Reduce of empty array with no initial value";

Array.prototype.reduceRight = function (f, acc) {
    let { length } = this;
    const noAcc = arguments.length < 2;
    if (noAcc && length === 0) throw new TypeError(REDUCE_ERROR);
    let result = noAcc ? this[--length] : acc;
    while (length > 0) result = f(this[--length], result, length, this);
    return result;
};
```

Since `result` represents the previous value (right-hand side value), it makes sense to make it the second parameter of the function `f`. The current value represents the left-hand side value. Hence, it makes sense to make the current value the first parameter of the function `f`. This way, even for non-commutative associative operations, the aforementioned relation holds true.

So, my questions are:

1. Doesn't it indeed make more sense for `reduceRight` to be implemented the way I did?
2. Why is the native `reduceRight` not implemented the way I did?

Comment: Isn't this just because [`foldr` and `foldl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) operate from different directions? That's the point of having both, and non-commutative operations will necessarily return different results.

Comment: @ssube They may operate in different directions but they should return the same result for associative operations. For example: `foldl1 (++) xs == foldr1 (++) xs` is `True` in Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't it indeed make more sense for `reduceRight` to be implemented the way I did?

Maybe. However, the JavaScript *array iterators* do not come from a pure functional programming background.

> Why is the native `reduceRight` not implemented the way I did?

Because it's simpler (easier to remember) to have the same parameter order, the accumulator always first.

The primitive operation on arrays is `reduce`, which iterates from 0 to n-1 as always. Only in Haskell with its recursively-built lists `foldr` makes more sense (has the `build` duality, works well lazily on infinite lists…). Notice how the naming is not `reduce`+`reduceLeft`…

Then `reduceRight` does not inverse the fold operation, it just *reverses* the *iteration* order. This is also how it is typically explained in documentation and tutorials, for example in *The Definitive Guide*:

> *`reduceRight()` works just like `reduce()`, except that it processes the array from  highest.*

Also the [first implementation](https://bug363040.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=248586) of `reduce`/`reduceRight` (see [Bug 363040](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363040)) in [Mozilla's *array extras*](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/jsarray.c#2878) for JS 1.8 followed this approach: It just flipped start with end and negated the step value.

The [notes of Dave Herman](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2009-March/009067.html) for the ES4 spec followed this line of thought. It does mention Haskell, but the whole document does not deal with the parameter order of the `callback` at all. Maybe the distinct order was lost in Haskells uncommon syntax, or the canonical type names so that both signatures began with `(a -> b -> …`. More discussion went into the [missing `thisObject` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14867946/1048572).

Some relevant excerpts:

> *The benefits [of the approach]:*
>
> - *just like Python => Python community mindshare*
> - *full generality of fold (left)*
> - *but also make the simple case, where the first element is the basis
>     element, simpler*
>
> *I'd guess most people find the left-to-right version of reduce more
>
>   intuitive, since they usually iterate over arrays from left to right. 
>   Plus that's what Python does.*
>
> *I think it would also be important to provide a reduceRight as well,
>
>   since not every operation is associative, and sometimes people need to
>   go from right to left.*

And finally, that is what [got into the EcmaScript spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=meetings:minutes_jun_03_2008&s=array+extras#minutes):

> ***Array extras***: Spec it the way it is currently supported in FF